# String to Date conversion in wrangler

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I am having my raw data in the format of '2019-10-10' in csv file.
After reading file I have loaded into Wrangler for transformation .
My target column is having data type as DATE.

I have applied below transformation:
set-column TODATE TODATE=UNIX_DATE('2019-10-10')

Here UNIX_DATE('2019-10-10') will convert date into Unix time stamp and post that Wrangler will take care while dumping into to Target table.

Here it is giving error like

Pipeline faile: jexl transformation wrong.

Expected result should be in 2019-10-10 format in target table.
Please help further.

Comment: Hi Darpan,
Th error indicates that the JEXL syntax provided is wrong. If I understand correctly, input to wrangler is string type for example, '2019-10-10'. What is the output type do you expect from wrangler?